# unequal spaces in ggplot histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I want to produce a histogram with ggplot, i have dataframe "plot_data"

```
plot_data<-data.frame(CLV.decile=unique(subset.customer_data$CLV.decile),
CLV=unique(subset.customer_data$mean.CLV.decile))
```

that looks like this

```
> plot_data
  CLV.decile  CLV
1         10 1560
2          5 1525
3          1 1512
```

This is the plot:

```
ylim <- c(0, 1.1*max(plot_data$CLV))

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=CLV.decile, y=CLV)) +
geom_histogram(stat="identity",fill="skyblue",colour="black") +
labs(x="Decile",y="CLV") + geom_text(aes(label=CLV), vjust=-1) + ylim(ylim) +
scale_x_reverse(breaks = plot_data$CLV.decile)
```

How can i fix that? Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly - try `x = factor(CLV.decile)` under `aes()`.

Comment: results in an error:Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(x) : - not meaningful for factors

Comment: Start with two lines - `ggplot()` and `geom_bar()` instead of histogram. And see where it leads now.

Comment: That's not a histogram. It's a barplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your x axis being continuous. Try this by using:

```
library(ggplot2)
ylim <- c(0, 1.1*max(plot_data$CLV))

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=as.factor(CLV.decile), y=CLV)) +
  geom_histogram(stat="identity",fill="skyblue",colour="black") +
  labs(x="Decile",y="CLV") + geom_text(aes(label=CLV), vjust=-1) + ylim(ylim) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=as.character(plot_data$CLV.decile))
```

You need to have `CLV.decile` as factor and then provide a `scale_x_discrete` to specify the order.

[image]

And the bars have equal spacing between them.

Edit:

This is essentially a barplot so you might as well consider changing `geom_histogram` to `geom_bar` with no change on the output.